# How to change 404 and 403 web pages to custom pages in localhost?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I want to customize 403 and 404 error pages? ( .htaccess file or CODE )

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in .htaccess file, considering the fact, that Apache looks for the specified document(s) within the site's root directory.

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /test/404.html // 404 page path
```

Comment: Is /test/404.html absolute path for that page ? My 404.php file is in Error folder in the root dir. So that can I change the .htaccess like ErrorDocument 404 /Error /404.php

Answer (score 0):

in .htaccess file put this line.

```
 ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

if you website is in sub folder then

```
 ErrorDocument 403 /subFolderName/403.php
 ErrorDocument 404 /subFolderName/404.php
```

Comment: Is this possible in localhost?

Comment: @SajithaLiyanage yes it's work in localhost; suppose yor project path is www/testProject/ then your rule will be `/testProject/404.php`